# Adding tables at run time in Telerik Reporting

Tags: telerik, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

I've been reading Telerik's documentation and I'm not sure if this is possible: I'm being asked to add tables to a report at run time, without doing so programmatically. A query is run that fetches hierarchical data, and the report owner would like to add a new table to the report for each member of the topmost parent, so that each topmost parent has their own table, with a text box title on top of the table containing the parent's name, in the following pattern:

TopParent1

[Parent1's table]

TopParent2

[Parent2's table]

...

Does anyone know how I could go about doing that without doing so programmatically? Every example and/or bit of documentation I've seen pertains to programmatically adding tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question as follows:

1. Create two blank reports.
2. On the report chosen to use for the detail report, remove the report header and footer.
3. Add data source and parameter/s to the detail report (in my case, an SQL data source) and set report data source to the data source created here.
4. Add group to report with the value of groupings set to the top-most result in query bound to report. (Groupings = Fields.Parent)
5. Create text box with the value set to the field for the top result (textbox1.Value = Fields.Parent) or use data explorer to drag and drop Fields.Parent into the group header.
6. Create text boxes to mimic table column heads (one text box for each title of the columns) and place them into the group header with the text box containing the topmost result (or Fields.Parent).
7. Drag or create text fields for the rest of the fields in the query (Fields.Child1, Fields.Child2, Fields.Child3, etc) in the detail section of the report, aligned vertically with their column header. Preview the report--it should contain a table-like structure that repeats on each top result.
8. Switch to other report.
9. Add same parameter/s to that report.
10. Add subreport item to the detail section of that report.
11. Set subreport report source to Type and report document, then select the name of the detail report (the first one created here).
12. Set parameter/s for subreport to the same parameter/s used in the subreport.

Using that, I was able to essentially add a table per item in the first column of the query. The report created first serves as a wrapper for the query, and because it's being placed in the other report as a subreport item with the grouping I created, it is allowed to repeat as much as it needs to in order to display all the rows in the query.

I used the Telerik documentation for [master-detail reports](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports-master-detail) and [report structures](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports-understanding-report-structure) for this.

Comment: It can also be set to visible/not visible via parameters and binding.

Answer (score 2):

> It is possible to add tables to a report at run time, without doing
>   so programmatically?

**R:** *It's not possible to add table with out saying programmatically : the size of each element , the exact position , etc .. .. ..*

### HowTo create a 'hierachical' report with conditional display ?

#### 1/. Hierachical Report.

Read [the telerik official tutorial](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports-master-detail) on **How to: Create a Master-Detail Report Using a SubReport Item**

Using the [SubReport report item](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/report-items-sub-report) you can display one report within another report. The data for each [SubReport](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/report-items-sub-report) can be completely different.

But You can achiev Parent/chield relation by [Passing Parameters to a SubReport](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/report-items-sub-report).

> /!\ Caution /!\
>   Page sections are not related to the report itself, but are relative to the paper or screen. Thus page sections of nested/detail reports are ignored and only the page sections of the main report are visible.

In order to have sections that repeat on every page similar to page sections, consider using an unbound group (no grouping criteria specified) and set the PrintOnEveryPage property of its sections to True. Be aware that you cannot use PageCount and PageNumber global objects in group sections.

#### 2/. Conditional Display

You will need to [hide Report if subreport have no result](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/details/how-to-show-no-data-message-or-hide-an-item-in-case-of-no-data).

If you want the user to choose if he want some sub report. 
You can do it by passing parameter from your calling application to your report constructor. 
And use Something like a Bitfield or an enum to choose what to display.

And What about a C# controler in the master report code behind ?

```cs
public myReportConstructor(int SubreportToDisplay)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Hiden_Display(SubreportToDisplay);
}

private void Hiden_Display(int _code)
{
    if ((_code & (int)myEnum.InfoClient) != (int)myEnum.InfoClient) 
        HideNShrink(SUBREPORT_CLIENT);
    if ((_code & (int)myEnum.Item) != (int)myEnum.Item) 
    { 
        HideNShrink(SUBREPORT_Product.Item1); 
        HideNShrink(SUBREPORT_Product.ItemTWO); 
    }
}

 private void HideNShrink(ReportItem target)
{// http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/details/collapse-the-container-when-hiding-child-report-items-
    target.Visible = false;
    target.Height = Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.Unit.Pixel(1); 
}
```

I use a little trick here in my designer every subreport item is set to public:

```cs
 private Telerik.Reporting.TextBox textBox17;
 public Telerik.Reporting.SubReport SubReport_Client;
 public Sub_Client sub_CLI1;
```

When hidding Client I will use the `SubReport_Client`.
That is the `SubReport item`, the container of my `SubReport Sub_Client` ;
(Yes they name the container and the containt are the same name, thats confusing at First, but it's Vs/Telerik choice)
When hidding a Sub Report That is in an other Sub Report.
I use the `ContaintSubReport`, Container of the nested-nested `SubReport`.
like: `sub_CLI1.nested-nested_SubReport`

Comment: Is there a way to add a subreport per top result (top-most parent/first column) in the query, and to add multiple items per page? I've been told not to add anything to their controllers, unfortunately, which keeps me from using any of the techniques I know to do this.

Comment: I know i 'm late but i dont get your question.
You can add infinite item per page.
Im pretty sure its doable with out adding things to their controllers. 
The old report must have all the information you need. You must 1rst define some some logic for the new report processing. Define each block to have a Datasource that have the correct information or can be filter to display the correct information. Make sure every thing needed is here ( parameters etc ..) 
The you will be create the sub report in a heartbeat , once you ve praticed a bit with Subreport, grouping and filtering.

Comment: Its the "Is there a way to add a subreport per top result (top-most parent/first column) in the query," that i dont get .. 
Can you had a [basical demo](http://www.telerik.com/clientsfiles/59c2c46b-791d-455a-9f2d-c7628c4d58e4_rptexmple.png) just an exel with color and no data but number and color is ok. 1 for the old version 1 for the new one

Comment: @wormwood I can't comment your answer cause i have low reputation. 
But here is the basic process you can find in the [telerik documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports-master-detail)
At least Add a link to it.

Comment: I can add a link, sure.